# parsing api version: yaml: line 11: did not find expected key

Tags: jenkins, skaffold, google-anthos

I'm getting the below error while trying to run the skaffold.yml

```
**Error:**
parsing api version: yaml: line 11: did not find expected key
```

**skaffold.yml**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: myaccount-nginx
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: repo.corp.cox.com:5011/cbma/core-ui

profiles:
- name: build
  build:
    tagPolicy:
      envTemplate:
        template: "{{.IMAGE_NAME}}:{{.MAJOR_VERSION}}.{{.MINOR_VERSION}}.{{.BUILD_NUMBER}}"
     artifacts:
     - image: repo.corp.cox.com:5011/cbma/core-ui
- name: qaa4
  manifests:
    kustomize:
      paths:
        - k8s/overlays/anthosqaa4
```

**Please note I'm trying to deploy my Pods to anthos environment.**

Tried running the skaffold.yml